# NSString not sending data to UITextField after Segue

Tags: ios5, nsstring, xcode4.2, uitextfield, segue

This issue has got me down for the last couple of days and it's irritating now as I'm wasting way too much time on this.

I've done NSLog() to see what's happening and it seems correct but I cannot understand why it's not sending the data. The code below it from the PrepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:id
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Confirm"]) {
        NSLog(@"Preparing to Segue");
        SubmitEventsP2 *subEventVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog(@"Set destination VC to *subEventVC");
        NSDate *choice = [ datePick date];
        NSLog(@"Assign date from picker to *choice");
        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyy HH:mm"];
        NSLog(@"Set the format of date and time");
        NSString *formatteddate = [format stringFromDate:choice];
        NSLog(@"Store the date format in *formatteddate");
        [subEventVC setDateField:formatteddate];    //Incompatible pointer types sending "NSString *" to parameter of type "UITextField *"
        NSLog(@"Should send the date to the textField");
        //      NSString *viewchange = @"SubmitEventsP2" ;
        NSLog(@"%@",formatteddate);
    }
}
```

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

If more information is needed let me know.

Thanks

EDIT:
The question has been amended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You should use `setDateField` (notice the capital D in Date) in your `[subEventVC setdateEvent...` line
2. The last line should be:

   NSLog(@"%@", formatteddate);

**Edit:**

Since dateField is a textfield, you should actually be using:

```
[subEventVC.dateField setText:formatteddate];
```

Comment: ok, thanks for reply so quickly, Done that, I've fiddled with it so much must have missed the wrong cased D in setDateField. ops...    I'm wondering now why I've got another issue. It's been amended.

Comment: ok, It's saying no getter method found in SubmitEventP2. Does that mean I need to delegate something. I've looked at many guides on this and I'm confused.

Comment: Well thats weird, loaded xcode up and the above issue has resolved itself... Still no data getting to the field though...

Answer (score 0):

Try feeding a NSString property in subEventVC first, then loading that into the textField on viewDidLoad in that class.  I suspect the textField can't be updated because it hasn't yet been created.

Comment: Nevermind on this, reading the above answer by @Inafziger I noticed I jumped the gun and answered something that had not been asked.